DIY Radio Telescope (High School)
Background:  I am attempting to build an RTL-SDR-based radio telescope for detecting hydrogen lines (21 cm) as a project with my HS Physics class. Several accounts are online, including parts lists and assembly instructions, and I am reasonably confident that I can get it working in a stationary "Scan as the Earth turns" mode.
How big a patch of sky will we be "seeing?"  If I view the celestial equator continuously and average the reading over 10 minutes, I will have 144 pixels or "buckets" of 2.5 degrees width.   The receiving antenna I am starting with is a commercially available WiFi antenna.
(2.4GHz 24DBI Directional High-Gain N-Type Female Aluminum Die Cast Grid Parabolic Antenna (ANT-GRID-24DBI))
with this listed
"Beam width/horizontal: 14 Beam width/vertical: 10 F/B ratio-db: >30"
Does the beam width mean I am looking at "buckets" of sky either 10 or 14 degrees across?
Is this 10-degrees the half-power beam width or the first null beam width?

A WiFi antenna (designed for 12 cm wavelength) will not perform well at 21 cm.

A very interesting project.  Is it possible to follow its development somewhere?

https://lweb.cfa.harvard.edu/~npatel/hornAntennaAASposterPDF2.pdf Could be of interest - build your own cheaply…

@dtn The original article inspiring the project is here
https://www.rtl-sdr.com/cheap-and-easy-hydrogen-line-radio-astronomy-with-a-rtl-sdr-wifi-parabolic-grid-dish-lna-and-sdrsharp/

@Jon Custer  Thank you for the resource.

https://physicsopenlab.org/2020/07/20/horn-antenna-for-the-21cm-neutral-hydrogen-line/ As well. Seems there are quite a variety of people who want to do something similar, so a little googling may go a long way. Excellent project, perhaps you could find a local ham radio operator/club to assist. The Amateur Radio SE may answer questions as well.
